# Paused on exception ReferenceError: closeAlert is not defined

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I am getting the following error

```
Paused on exception
ReferenceError: closeAlert is not defined
```

on a laravel project using blade.I have the following html code where I am loading the javascript using vite

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> @vite('resources/js/app.js') @vite('resources/js/custom.js')
  <title>Sign In</title>
</head>

<body class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-screen bg-custom-gray">
  <div class="w-full max-w-lg p-8 mb-8 bg-custom-gray md:bg-white shadow-0 md:shadow-lg lg:shadow-lg lg:bg-white">
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
      <div class="flex justify-center">
        <a href="https://www.test.com/"><img src="/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
      </div>
      <h3 class="text-2xl font-bold text-center text-white mt-9 md:text-custom-gray lg:text-custom-gray">Testing</h3>
      <p class="mt-2 text-center text-white md:text-custom-gray lg:text-custom-gray">
        Test in progess.
      </p>
    </div>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login.custom') }}">
      @csrf
      <div class="mt-6">
        <div>
          <label class="block font-bold text-white md:text-custom-gray lg:text-custom-gray" for="email">Email<label>
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="mt-2 w-full p-3 rounded border-2 md:border lg:border {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'border-red-600' : 'border-custom-green' }}  focus:outline-none focus:border-orange-500 md:focus:border-blue-600  lg:focus:border-blue-600 font-normal">
                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                            <span class="text-xs font-normal tracking-wide text-red-600">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
                        @endif
                </div>
                <label class="block mt-4 font-bold text-white md:text-custom-gray lg:text-custom-gray" for="email">Password</label>
          <div class="relative w-full mt-1">
            <div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center px-2 py-2">
              <input class="hidden js-password-toggle" id="toggle" type="checkbox" />
              <label class="mt-1.5 bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 rounded px-2 py-1 text-sm text-gray-600 cursor-pointer js-password-label " for="toggle">show</label>
            </div> <input id="password" name="password" type="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="password" class="js-password mt-2 w-full p-3 rounded border-2 md:border lg:border  {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'border-red-600' : 'border-custom-green' }}  focus:outline-none focus:border-orange-500 md:focus:border-blue-600  lg:focus:border-blue-600 font-normal">
          </div>
          @if ($errors->has('password'))
          <span class="text-xs font-normal tracking-wide text-red-600">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</span> @endif
          <div class="mt-9">
            <button class="w-full px-6 py-4 mt-4 text-lg font-bold text-white rounded focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 bg-custom-green">Continue</button>
          </div>
          <div class="justify-center w-full mt-4 text-sm font-normal text-center text-white md:text-blue-600 lg:text-blue-600">
            Forgot your password ? <a href="{{ route('forgot') }}" class="font-bold text-white md:text-blue-600 lg:text-blue-600 hover:underline">Reset Password</a> if you don't have an account <a href="{{ route('user') }}" class="font-bold text-white md:text-blue-600 lg:text-blue-600 hover:underline">Create Account</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    </div>
    <footer class="mb-4 text-xs text-center text-gray-200">
      &copy; <span id="year">2024</span> Testing&trade;. All Rights Reserved.
    </footer>
</body>
@if(true)
<div id="alert" class="fixed z-20 flex p-4 mb-4 text-white border-l-4 drop-shadow-md top-4 right-4 w-96 bg-custom-green" role="alert">
  <svg class="flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 10a8 8 0 11-16 0 8 8 0 0116 0zm-7-4a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zM9 9a1 1 0 000 2v3a1 1 0 001 1h1a1 1 0 100-2v-3a1 1 0 00-1-1H9z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
  <div class="ml-3 font-medium">
    {{ session('success') }}
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="closeAlert()" class="ml-auto -mx-1.5 -my-1.5 bg-green-50 text-green-500 rounded-lg focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-400 p-1.5 hover:bg-green-200 inline-flex h-8 w-8 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-green-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700"
    data-dismiss-target="#alert-border-3" aria-label="Close">
      <span class="sr-only">Dismiss</span>
      <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
    </button>
</div>
@endif

</html>
```

The custom.js file is as follows

```js
function closeAlert() {
  var alertBox = document.getElementById("alert");
  alertBox.style.display = "none";
}
// Password toggle functionality
const passwordToggle = document.querySelector('.js-password-toggle');
passwordToggle.addEventListener('change', function() {
  const password = document.querySelector('.js-password'),
    passwordLabel = document.querySelector('.js-password-label');

  if (password.type === 'password') {
    password.type = 'text';
    passwordLabel.innerHTML = 'hide';
  } else {
    password.type = 'password';
    passwordLabel.innerHTML = 'show';
  }

  password.focus();
})

// Close the alert message after 5 seconds
const alertBox = document.getElementById('alert');
if (alertBox) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    alertBox.remove();
  }, 5000);
}
```

The rest of the javascript works except for the function i.e `closeAlert()`.
When I try to click the close button with the closeAlert function I get the error described abover.The other javascript code in the external js file works as intended I only have issues with the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways you can go about this, either setting an event listener for your button to run the function within your JavaScript file or allowing global access to the function by storing it in the context of the window.

**Event Listener (reccomended)**

```js
document.getElementById("YourButtonId").addEventListener("click", closeAlert);
```

**Using window**

```js
window.closeAlert = function() {
    //Your function code here
}
```

Comment: why is using the context of the window not recommended